# Is it possible to redirect a trailing slash page ending to .php in a different folder/subfolder?

Tags: php, redirect, trailing-slash

I've seen lots of examples of redirecting all the files in a folder using rewrite rules, but is it possible (and if so, how!) to redirect a page ending with a trailing slash to a completely different page ending with .php in a different folder or subfolder? Can it be done on a page by page basis rather than a single rewrite rule?

I can do it in .htaccess with pages that have endings, but it doesn't work when one of the file names ends in a training slash.

For example, how would:

http://www.pokertips.org/weekly.shuffle/archives/2014-02-02/

redirect to

http://www.pokertips.org/weekly.shuffle/articles/tips-moving-up-limits.php